# Using an HTML Java applet to host a jar file - Security issues

Tags: java, applet

I'm hosting a website to share a game I'm working on. As a .jar file, the game can be run (It only works with Java 8, not 7. That's not my main issue though.)

My site is http://efight.me/ and as it stands, I have a download button for the jar (all hosted with my github account) but I want it to be able to run in browser like a flash game.

When I set it up to run as an HTML applet, I get a popup saying that it has been blocked for security reasons. Is there a way around this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

in order to run a java applet you need certain permissions, to get that you need a certificate, or a signature. they can vary in cost, but you could also sign your own applet, letting the user know which permissions your applet needs. They will still get prompted if they trust your applet, but they will be able to run your code if they trust it.
Look for a tutorial on how to sign your applet its quite a long process.
good luck.
Here are the steps to allow thru security:

[image: click home]

[image: go to security tab]

[image: edit site list]

Comment: I have self signed my applet and it still got blocked.

Comment: did you refresh the signature? remember those have certain time to live. Also, on internet explorer with high security, the user must manually go to "configure java" on their PC and allow java applets from your site otherwise they get automatically blocked.

Comment: I just signed it, this is what the error message looks like http://imgur.com/uCgUTn1

Comment: I added the images to allow a site to run

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like for the user to not have to change their Java security settings